# Using paste() during lapply with ggplot and two different data sources

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

Consider a list of ggplots:

```
list1 <- vector("list", 7)
names(list1) <- LETTERS[1:7]
list1 <- lapply(list1, function(x) {x <- ggplot(data.frame()) + geom_point() + xlim(0, 10) + ylim(0, 100);x})
```

I could use

```
list1 <- lapply(list1, function(x) {x <- x + annotate("text", label="some text", x=4, y=4)})
```

to annotate some text into each plot and plot the whole list with

```
lapply(names(list1), 
       function(x) ggsave(filename=paste(x,".jpg",sep=""), plot=list1[[x]]))
```

but the text i want to annotate into each plot is variable and stored in another vector:

```
somevec <- runif(7)
```

So, i need something like:

```
list1 <- lapply(list1, function(x) {x <- x + annotate("text", label=paste(somevec[x]), x=4, y=4);x})
```

but this does not work:

```
Error in somevec[x] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

So, how can i paste the *i*-th value in `somevec` into the *i*-th plot of `list1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `Map` instead

```
out <- Map(function(x, y) x + 
      annotate('text', label = y, x = 4, y = 4), list1, as.character(somevec))
```

---

Or if we want to use `lapply`, loop over the sequence

```
out <- lapply(seq_along(list1), function(i)
        list1[[i]] +  annotate('text', label = somevec[i], x = 4, y = 4))
```

Comment: Marking this as solution, because it was a bit faster, i think! In your lapply-alternative, at least for me, the names of out are not preserved. Just FYI

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your example is that you are trying to use the plot as an index for `somevec`, `x` here is a ggplot plot and not an integer like 1 or 2, useful for retrieving elements from `somevec`. The example below shows how to make a new list with the annotation

```r
require(ggplot2)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
list1 <- vector("list", 7)
names(list1) <- LETTERS[1:7]
list1 <- lapply(list1, function(x) {x <- ggplot(data.frame()) + geom_point() + xlim(0, 10) + ylim(0, 100);x})
somevec <- runif(7)
plist<-mapply(function(x,y){x+annotate("text", label=paste(y), x=4, y=4)}, list1, somevec, SIMPLIFY=F)
plist[[1]]
```

[image]